# Custom Visualforce Component Help

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

i want to build a custom visualforce component as shown in following image. I am currently thinking of a custom MultiPickList using div and ul. But i will have to write a lot of javascript for it.

So, I want to ask for some tips as to how can i build it efficiently. Also i am open to other ideas if i can achieve similar functionality by changing GUI.

[image: Custom Visualforce Component]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [Salesforce JavaScript Remoting integration](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-ext-common) for Sencha Ext JS. The [sample code](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-ext-common-samplecode) demonstrates how to read hierarchical data.

[image]

Then you could add [drag+drop](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html) between a TreePanel and a GridPanel.
[image: dragdrop]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this project might help you out.
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-dnd3.html

http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/